# Compile QT Error

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, nmake

I would like to compile `QT 5.9.3` with `Visual Studio 2017`. I was changing the the `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG` to `-Zi -MD` instead of `-Zi -MDd` in the file `C:\Qt\5.9.3-x86\qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf`.

However, when I configure with

```
configure -debug -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -opensource -platform win32-msvc -prefix C:\Qt\5.9.3-x86\5.9.3-x86-install
```

and run `nmake` after that, I always get an error for unresolved external symbol `__imp___CrtDbgReporterW` like the following image shows:

[image: Qt compiler error]

I figured out that this is due to symbols that are available in Debug-mode but not available in Release-mode.
So I added an `NDEBUG`-option following [this post](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60776%20ge%C3%A4ndert). But without luck. I also tried advancing `QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG` to `-Zi -MD -D"NDEBUG"`. But this yielded no luck as well.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to fix this? I need the Debug libraries compiled with the `/MD` instead of the `/MDd` flag.

**--- Edit ---**

Redirecting the ouput of the VS2017 Command Prompt shows that the file *Debug2.cpp* has the link command

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DEF:..\..\..\3rdparty\angle\src\libGLESv2\libGLESv2d.def /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\..\..\lib\libGLESv2d.dll @C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nm88DB.tmp
```

which results in the *unresolved external symbols* error.

Comment: Can you show us the build command for a source file and link command for a DLL that are generated by your settings?

Comment: @metal I'm not sure, if I selected a fitting example: Is the `Makefile` from folder *qtactive* sufficient? I put the code into pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/WwNhPyUt

Comment: I want to see the actual command line that it is running for one source file and one DLL so I can see all the flags and such that are applied. Parsing the Makefile to figure that out is a pain.

Comment: @metal the output for a source file is here: https://pastebin.com/v74R2JZx

Comment: I redirected the output to a file.
The contents are here: pastebin.com/UEaLaZfE where one can see that nmake does not build with the **NDEBUG** Flag while building the file *Debug2.cpp* ending with the external symbol error.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you pasted has some problems.

First of all, it is using command files (e.g., `@C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\nm88DB.tmp` on the linker command line), so we still can't see all the commands passed to the linker.

Second, you have both `NDEBUG` and `_DEBUG` defined for the same cpp file (e.g., line 1117). The presence of the latter is likely the cause of your linker problems because it can affect how it automatically finds the CRT.

This will likely be solved by (1) getting consistent preprocessor defines and (2) making sure you have the default libraries on your command line. (Specifically, you may need to add or remove something like `/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT` and `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT`on your linker command line. I think you should have the latter but not the former for your case.)

See [this article from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/abx4dbyh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for info about which libraries and defines should go together.

Comment: I will try to do this. As a temporary workaround I extended the configure parameters with the parameters **-no-angle -opengl desktop** This prevents angle from being built and therefore preventing the error in file *Debug2.cpp*